# How to detect `focusin` support?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, browser-feature-detection, focusin

Thanks to [Perfection kills](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/), we can use the following JavaScript to detect event support:

```
function hasEvent(ev) {
    var elem = document.createElement('a'),
        type = 'on' + ev,
        supported = elem[type] !== undefined;
    if (!supported) {
        elem.setAttribute(type, 'return;');
        supported = typeof elem[type] === 'function';
    }
    elem = null;
    return supported;
}
```

This works for about the only time I need it: detecting `mouseenter` support; `hasEvent('mouseenter')` will return false in Chrome, Firefox, etc., as it should.

But now I'm trying to "fix" browsers that don't support the `focusin` and `focusout` events. [According to PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html), that's basically just Firefox. Unfortunately, Chrome and Safari are listed as having "incomplete" support, for the following reason:

> Safari and Chrome fire these events only with addEventListener; not with traditional registration.

In general, that's fine; I'd only be using `addEventListener` anyway. It *does* mean, however, that detecting support via `elem.onfocusin !== undefined` won't work. I tested it out, and it's true:

```
<p>Do I support <a href="#">focusin</a>?</p>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

// hasEvent method defined here
function listener() {
    var response = hasEvent('focusin') ? 'Yes!' : 'No...';
    alert(response);
}

elem.addEventListener('focusin', listener, false);
</script>
```

The above alerts `No...` in Chrome! Is there any way to detect whether the browser supports `focusin`, without using browser sniffing?

Comment: is there a difference between mouseenter & mouseover? or focusin & focus? or focusout & blur?

Comment: @Ibu `mouseenter` doesn't bubble, while `mouseover` does; `focusin`/`focusout` *do* bubble, `focus`/`blur` don't.

Comment: Another important fact is that focusin and focusout event objects have the `relatedTarget` property which points to the element that has lost/received focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses the fact that calling `focus()` triggers `focusin`: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/YXeD3/.

The element *must* be visible and inserted into the DOM, otherwise `focusin` is not fired for some reason.

```
var result = (function() {
    var hasIt = false;

    function swap() {
        hasIt = true; // when fired, set hasIt to true
    }

    var a = document.createElement('a'); // create test element
    a.href = "#"; // to make it focusable
    a.addEventListener('focusin', swap, false); // bind focusin

    document.body.appendChild(a); // append
    a.focus(); // focus
    document.body.removeChild(a); // remove again

    return hasIt; // should be true if focusin is fired
})();
```

Comment: I like the idea but this detection method is a bit obstrusive as it changes the active element on the page.

Comment: This answer would be made better if it also prevented the temporary anchor element from receiving focus. Then it would have no observable side effects. (Like stealing focus. What if an element on the page tried to autofocus when the page loads?)

Answer (score 4):

focusin & focusout should be fired BEFORE target element receives focus, event order is also seems buggy

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-focusevent-event-order

currently, only IE works according to spec:

```
Chrome/Safari:
focus
focusin
DOMFocusIn
blur
focusout
DOMFocusOut
focus
focusin
DOMFocusIn

Opera 12:
focus
DOMFocusIn
focusin
blur
DOMFocusOut
focusout
focus
DOMFocusIn
focusin

IE 8:
focusin
focus
focusout
focusin
blur
focus

Firefox 14:
focus
blur
focus
```

Comment: Well, spec has been written following IE's behavior, so it's not really surprising.

Comment: but IE behavior is good, ie support event.toElement/event.fromElement, other browsers doesn't support relativeTarget/toElement/fromElement for this event

Answer (score 0):

You can test for `("onfocusin" in document)`.

This method has the advantage of being light and unobtrusive and <s>it will tell you whether the browser supports the `focusin` event.</s> (not on Chrome, sorry)

You may use the following code to get the same behaviour as the `focusin` event on all browsers (IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Edge):

```
var eventName, useCapture;
if ("onfocusin" in document) {
  eventName = "focusin";
  useCapture = false;
} else {      
  eventName = "focus";
  useCapture = true;
}

document.body.addEventListener(eventName, function( event ) {
    event.target.style.background = "pink";    
  }, useCapture);
```

JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d306qm92/2/

More information about the Firefox workaround here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus#Event_delegation

**UPDATE**: As said above, the test will wrongly say "false" on Chrome, nonetheless the code sample will work as intended as Chrome supports both methods (`focusin` and `focus` with `useCapture`).

Comment: It doesn't matter about Chrome, because with Chrome you won't have the need to use focusin and focus. for example the js addEventListener visibilitychange