# How to detect if browser support offline event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've try to use code from this question: [How to detect `focusin` support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337670/how-to-detect-focusin-support)

but for Chromium that supports `offline` event `hasEvent('offline')` return false. Anybody know how to detect offline/online events in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that online and offline events start on body and bubble up so you can't use div to detect it. But I've created this code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.setAttribute('ononline', 'return;')
typeof body.ononline == 'function';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`return !!window.applicationCache;`

If I understand properly your question, you also may want to read [this article](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html).

**EDIT:**

Basically you can use the following function:

```
function reportConnectionEvent(e)
{
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    if ('online' == e.type) {
        alert( 'The browser is ONLINE.' );
    }
    else if ('offline' == e.type) {
        alert( 'The browser is OFFLINE.' );
    }
    else {
        alert( 'Unexpected event: ' + e.type );
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.ononline = reportConnectionEvent;
    document.body.onoffline = reportConnectionEvent;
}
```

Also you may check this for demo http://html5demos.com/offline-events

Comment: I don't need to have app that work offline, I need to detect the event because I need to add ajax request to queue and when internet is back I need to send them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`'onoffline' in window`

or

`'onoffline' in document.body`

Comment: this not bulletproff check, every even check test also check if event work correctly not only if it's present.

Comment: @jcubic LOL how would you check it "works correctly"? :)

Comment: And this method is widely used and robust enough for modernizr but somehow not for you (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/isEventSupported.js). Kinda not cool to accept your own answers making stuff in more complex manner.

Comment: I've seen this in other SO question about events  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877393/detecting-support-for-a-given-javascript-event where you test if the value is a function.