# JQuery focusin behaves differently in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an HTML table with an `input` field in each cell. On `focusin` I append a `div` (basically a resizable overlay) to the cell.
Jquery code:

```
$("input").on("focusin", function(){
  var selectionDiv = $("<div class='selection-div'><a href='#'></a></div>");
  $(this).parent().prepend(selectionDiv);
  selectionDiv.resizable();
  console.log("focusin");
}).on("focusout", function(){
  $(this).prev().remove();
  console.log("focusout");
});
```

The problem comes when I click in the cell. In Chrome the `div` is appended and the `input` gets the focus. When I click the same cell again, `focusout` and `focusin` gets called, and the `div` is appended again.

However in IE 11, when I click the second time on the same cell, only `focusout` is called and the `div` is removed. What is causing this behaviour?

I have a jsbin here: 
http://jsbin.com/tasujuzoqo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: It would appear that focusin and focusout are not supported in all browsers yet, at least not Firefox (not directly related to your question but just an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin).  What's preventing you from using focus and blur events?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but firefox is irrelevant for me. `focusin` is supported in both IE and Chrome. Or do you think `focus` and `blur` would behave the same way in IE and Chrome?

Comment: In my experience, focus and blur are much more established and dependable events if you are thinking cross-browser.  You are right focusin and focusout are technically supported in both IE and Chrome, but that doesn't mean they will act the same way.  This is an interesting related post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337670/how-to-detect-focusin-support